# How to find the probability of an event "B" when given the probability of event A and the probability of the union of A and B?

Tags: probability, independence

If P(A U B) = 0.4 and P(A) = 0.3, find P(B) if A and B are independent.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Inclusion-exclusion (*which is always true*) implies that $$P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

If we were to assume that $A$ and $B$ are independent, that would imply (*and be true if and only if*) that $$P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$$

> So, $0.4 = 0.3 + P(B) - 0.3\cdot P(B)$.  Solve for $P(B)$.

Comment: Thanks that is perfect! I was not making the connection and ignored that implication for independence.